# What is the difference between syntax error and runtime error?

Tags: python, dynamic, syntax, runtime

For example:

```
def tofloat(i): 
    return flt(i)

def addnums(numlist):
    total = 0
    for i in numlist:
        total += tofloat(i)
    return total

nums = [1 ,2 ,3]
addnums(nums)
```

The `flt` is supposed to be `float`, but I'm confused whether it is a syntax error or a runtime error.

Comment: I have to say, you ask some pretty interesting questions :). +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, it is a runtime error, because Python will try to resolve the `flt` name during runtime (because it's a dynamic language), and it won't find it. When this happens, Python yields and exception saying that it couldn't find the symbol you were using `flt` and all this happens at runtime.

Syntax errors happen when the interpreter find something not compelling with Python's syntax. For example: The Python's grammar doesn't recognize the input syntax as a valid Python program. This may happen when:

1. You forgot to add `:` at the end of an `if, def, class`, etc expression
2. You forgot to close some parenthesis or brackets, etc.
3. A lot of places else when you don't adhere to python's grammar :)

In your example, there is nothing wrong with the grammar. For the interpreter, `flt(i)` is a very valid call to a `flt` method which had to be check at runtime within the scopes if it really exists. So the interpreter won't complaint and the syntax of your problem is good.

Actually, this can be seen as a disadvantage over *compiled languages* like C#, C++, etc. This kind of errors can be detected sooner at compile time, and the compiler screams loud when it find it so you can notice it.

With dynamic languages, you won't notice this until the actual method is called. Your program is simple, so you may find it quick. But, what about the missing `o` in `float` was inside some legacy framework within a subclass of a subclass of a class, as a property, inside some other module, etc. That would be harsh :)

**UPDATE:** [The execution model](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html) in Python's docs are a great read if you're into how does Python internals works. This will clarify your doubt further and will give you a lot of knowledge :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: It should also be noted that in Python, a syntax error is technically a runtime error since it occurs at runtime. This is not true for compiled languages, though - they differentiate between compile-time errors (such as syntax errors) and runtime errors (such as null pointer errors).

Comment: @PauloBu,could you please check this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652075/showing-the-checked-item-alone-without-check-box

Answer (score 2):

[SyntaxError](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SyntaxError) is raised by parser when it founds that your syntax is not correct, like missing colons, parenthesis, invalid statements etc. It'll not allow you to execute your code until you don't fix that the issue.

Your code will throw only error at runtime, i.e when the function `tofloat(i)` is called for the first time, so it is a runtime error. Specifically `NameError`.

Also a runtime error won't stop your program's execution until that buggy part is not executed. So, your code can actually run fine if you don't call `tofloat` ever.

The code below executes properly up to third line but then stops as `NameError` is raised.(a runtime error)

```
print 1
print 2
print 3     
print foo
```

**output:**

```
1
2
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 4, in <module>
    print foo
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

This code won't execute as we made a `SyntaxError`, even though the first 3 lines are perfectly okay:

```
print 1
print 2
print 2
print (foo
```

**Output:**

```
$ python so.py
  File "so.py", line 5

              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Note that there's also a `RunTimeError` in python, which is raised when an error is detected that doesn't fall in any of the other categories

Answer (score 0):

You have a `NameError`, Your code should read:

```
def tofloat(i): 
    return float(i)
```

There is no `flt` method in Python, that is why it is not working for you.

Incidentally, you really don't need to wrap that float casting into a function, and your whole code can be written as:

```
def addnums(numlist):
    return sum(map(float, numlist))
```

Using it:

```
>>> addnums(range(4))
6.0
```

Comment: That's why the question said "The flt suppose to be float()" (which you have changed with your edit to be more confusing). It's just asking what type of error it is.